# Unlist and create number for each list element and each value

Tags: r, list

I have a list like this:

```
mylist <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E"), "F")
mylist

[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "F"
```

I wish to convert the list to a data frame like below. I know how to create a vector of the values using `unlist`. But I also want a column with a number for each list element ("List"), and a number for each value within each list element ("id"):

| Desc | List | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 3 |
| D | 2 | 1 |
| E | 2 | 2 |
| F | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape2::melt` has a method for lists. Then add the 'id' using `sequence` on the `lengths` of each list element:

```
transform(reshape2::melt(mylist), id = sequence(lengths(mylist)))
  value L1 id
1     A  1  1
2     B  1  2
3     C  1  3
4     D  2  1
5     E  2  2
6     F  3  1
```

Or in `base`:

```
len = lengths(mylist)
data.frame(x = unlist(mylist), List = rep(seq_along(len), len), id = sequence(len))
  x List id
1 A    1  1
2 B    1  2
3 C    1  3
4 D    2  1
5 E    2  2
6 F    3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `stack` + `ave`

```
type.convert(
  transform(
    setNames(
      stack(setNames(mylist, seq_along(mylist))),
      c("Desc", "List")
    ),
    id = ave(seq_along(unlist(mylist)), List, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
  Desc List id
1    A    1  1
2    B    1  2
3    C    1  3
4    D    2  1
5    E    2  2
6    F    3  1
```

**Data**

```
mylist <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E"), "F")
```